# preencher input da direita pra esquerda

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Preciso que dois `input` que tenho em um app sejam preenchidos da direita para a esquerda...

um dos inputs é valor em reais (R$) o outro é valor em mililitro (ml), estou usando uma mascara do jquery (a [MaskMoney](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney) funciona certinho mais não no mobile, então optei por outra mascara [jQuery.maskdinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput)) aparentemente funciona no mobile, mas preenche o `input` da esquerda para direita, ao contrario do MaskMoney, e com isso fica uns espaços em branco, ou se não para preencher um valor monetário tem que colocar o 0 a esqueda para ter por exempo (R$ 09,00) para ter nove reais.

Acredito que se conseguir preencher os input da direita para a esquerda, o problema se resolva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito é procurar um plugin que se adeque às suas necessidades. A menos, claro, que você tenha um requisito bem específico e opte por desenvolver sua própria biblioteca.

Então comece por aqui:

http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/mask/
ou
http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/currency/

Tente com este aqui: http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Ou este aqui : https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 3):

Solução utilizando `text-align`:

```css
input {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

As soluções abaixo usando o atributo [dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) devem ser aplicadas somente para idiomas que são escritos da direita para a esquerda (como o árabe):

Com *HTML* utilizando o atributo `dir='rtl'` (right to left):

```html
<input name="DinheiroQueEhBomEuNaoTenho" dir="rtl" />
```

Com *CSS* através da propriedade `direction`.

> A propriedade direction define a direção em que o texto é escrito.

[Definição - direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/direction)

Veja um exemplo:

```css
input{
  direction: RTL;
}
```

```html
<input name="DinheiroQueEhBomEuNaoTenho" />
```

Comment: Não conhecia @Caique esse atributo do css, mas aqui ficou um pouco estranho, o cursor fica perdido enquanto digito... estou no Chrome não sei se no mozila acontece mesma coisa, vou testar

Comment: No mozilla funciona um pouco melhor... Obrigado pela ajuda!